# Error occured in deployment step 'Retract Solution'

Tags: deployment, solution-package

I have an error I never saw.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution':
>   C:\Windows\Temp\solution-3e36fbcd-ca01-4f9a-a3bb-31b0db0a0b74\foo.wsp
>   could not be created because the contents could not be found under id
>   ea41ac8e-c568-4223-816f-5d79a68970f0 in the configuration database.

I would like to provide relevant code to help you help me, but I have no idea why I have this error... Any lead?

Comment: Restart the Timer service and try again

Comment: @TARUN It didn't solve the problem (you're talking about SPTimerV4 right ?)

Comment: Do you try to retract the solution from Central Administration? or try to retract it using PowerShell https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607873.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

It looks there is some issue with your solution package

Once the deployment fails ..then retraction too fails ..so only way to solve this problem:

A. Removing that solution using remove option in Central Admin

B. Remove the artifacts manually from the deployed folders, anyway you are going to deploy the solution ..so this step is optional

C. Fix your solution package, then redeploy that again

If your deployment target is WFE ..then make sure you use DeploymentServerType = "WebFrontEnd, so that solution will not be deployed into your application servers

Please stop SharePoint Timer service before deploying.

```
<Solution
  DeploymentServerType = "WebFrontEnd">
</Solution>
```